# Installing New Network Drivers Without a Network Driver

Tags: wifi-driver

I’m running Win8 on a laptop with only USB and MicroSD support (thus, no Ethernet). 
I’m unable to connect to the Internet, and the Network Adapter (an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165) is returning a Code 10 (“This device cannot start”). 
Assuming it’s not a hardware problem, what should I do to be able to reconnect to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver package from the manufacturer's website (if you're gonna give more details on the device we can try to find the correct drivers) to a flash drive and installing it.

Another option to try is just uninstalling the device driver in Device Manager and restarting Windows to see if it comes but on its own and correctly.

Comment: The Network Device itself is an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165, And the machine I’m on is an Insignia NS-P11W7100.

Comment: [this](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/downloads/eula/27989/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-Windows-10?httpDown=https%3A%2F%2Fdownloadmirror.intel.com%2F27989%2Fa08%2FWiFi_20.70.0_PROSet64_Win10.exe) should be the correct driver

Comment: Oy... With a 'brand' like Insignia there aren't really any manufacturer place to get drivers 

Comment: @NordlysJeger I’m running Windows 8. Will that driver still work?

Comment: how could I not see the OS before? doesn't matter, [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27990/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-Windows-8-1-?product=89450) is the driver for win 8.x select your architecture at the left size to download the correct package.

Comment: @NordlysJeger Shouldn't that be an answer? Your comment is much more useful than the generic answer.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Just added an answer for this. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27990/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-Windows-8-1-?product=89450) should be the correct driver for your NIC. Select the correct architecture on the left site, accept the License agreement and copy it on a USB-Stick to install it on the laptop.